# {"Anulada la solicitud: No se puede crear un canal seguro SSL/TLS."}

Tags: c#, json, api

Estoy consumiendo una API en la que cuando la ejecuto en mi equipo, me va bien, pero cuando ejecuto el proyecto en servidor, me da el error de `{"Anulada la solicitud: No se puede crear un canal seguro SSL/TLS."}`

A nivel de código fuente tengo la línea
`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

pero no sé porqué me aparece esta incidencia.
Os agredezco cualquier ayuda que me podais dar.

```
public static void GetClients(string Key)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var url = $"https://api.appsat.net/v1/Clientes/";
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Add("key", Key);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Accept = "application/json";

            try
            {
                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream strReader = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        if (strReader == null) return;
                        using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(strReader))
                        {
                            string responseBody = objReader.ReadToEnd();
                            DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody, typeof(DataTable));
                            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                if (isClientSage(row))
                                {                         //MIRA SI ES CLIENT A SAGE
                                    Console.Write(getCodi(row) + " " + getcliente_nombre_comercial(row));
                                    Console.WriteLine();
                                }
                                else
                                {                                         //EL DONA D'ALTA A SAGE
                                    AltaClienteASage(row, Key);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                // Handle error
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Quizá debas usar tls11?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero he probado tanto TLS como TLS11 y persiste el error :/

Comment: Cuando hago consultas a API siempre uso la clase Http y nunca tuve problemas, no recuerdo configurar TLS.

Answer (score 1):

Yo pude resolver el problema en Powershell utilizando TLS12:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Creo que en C# sea muy parecido.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].